# tabBarをまたいで他のタブの下層ページに遷移したい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, iphone

以下のような画面を持ったiPhoneアプリを作りたいと考えています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この中のFirstViewから、SecondViewの次の画面の「ここに直接飛びたい」（以下、ターゲット画面）というところに遷移させたいです。

FirstViewの「移動」ボタンからSegueでターゲット画面につなぐと、遷移はできますがTabBarが表示されなくなります。
FirstViewに、

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
```

と書けばSecondViewには遷移しますが、ターゲット画面への遷移はできません。

このような場合、どのような処理でターゲット画面へ遷移することが一般的なのでしょうか。
ご教示頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### どのような処理でターゲット画面に遷移することが一般的なのか?

このような遷移自体が一般的ではないため、一般的な処理方法というのもありません。

ご存知かと思いますが、iOSでは通常の画面遷移も、`UINavigationController`内の画面遷移も、スタック状に管理されており、ツリー構造になっています。別の枝の途中に直接遷移する、なんてことはサポートされていません。

iOS用のアプリを作成されるなら、マルチウインドウのPC用アプリや、Webアプリでの感覚を引きずらずに、iOSに適した画面遷移となるよう、設計を見直すことをお勧めしておきます。

以下に「見かけは動いているように見せられるけど」と言う回答をお示ししますが、詳細な挙動を調べてもらえれば、あなたのアプリには採用できないようなものであるかもしれません。そのような場合には、あなたのアプリではどのような動作をさせたいのかの詳細をご質問に追記してみてください。

#### `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1`と書いてもターゲット画面に遷移できない

`UITabBarController`的にみると、`selectedIndex = 1`のview controllerは、SecondViewController (今回の問題には本質的ではないですが、iOSプログラミングではviewとview controllerは共に大変重要な要素なので、view controllerを〜Viewと呼称することはやめた方が良いでしょう)ではなく、`UINavigationController`なので、その`UINavigationController`に「ターゲット画面に遷移させておく」と言うことは、出来なくはありません。

```
    @IBAction func 移動1Action(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let storyboard = self.storyboard else {
            print("Storyboard not used")
            return
        }
        let targetVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ここに直接行きたい")
        if let navVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? UINavigationController {
            if !(navVC.topViewController is ここに直接行きたいVC) {
                navVC.pushViewController(targetVC, animated: false)
            }
        }
        self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    }
```

一体なぜこのような画面遷移が必要になるのか、目的をはっきりさせれば、より良い回答が得られるでしょう。

Comment: ご教示頂いた書き方で、無事希望通りの遷移を実現できました。
本当にありがとうございます。
こういった遷移は一般的ではないのですね…
例えばなのですが、A画面(First)でファイルを一覧表示したりお気に入りをClipしたりして、B画面(Second)でClipしたファイルを参照するようなアプリを考えていたのですが、Clipした際はB画面の詳細画面(target)に遷移させる、というのをやりたかったのですが…
仰る通り、Webアプリでの感覚を引きずっていたのかもしれません。
画面遷移含め、仕様から見直してみたいと思います。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @troublemaker さん、ご丁寧なコメントありがとうございます。セグエでつないでばかりだとわかりにくいかもしれませんが、そのような用途のtarget画面をA画面からもB画面からも開けられるようにする、と言うのはよくある画面デザインです。画面遷移ツリーの中の特定の枝に飛ぶ、と言う発想は捨て、また場合によってはタブバーなんて隠れても良い、と割り切れば、iOSの画面遷移の原則を損なわないでいろいろできる方法はあるかと思います。ぜひご自身のアプリに最適のやり方を見つけて、良いアプリにしていって下さい。

Comment: @OOPerさん、こちらこそコメントありがとうございます。「タブバーを諦める」という選択肢は一瞬頭をよぎったのですが、「画面遷移ツリーの中の特定の枝に飛ぶという発想を捨てる」というのは考えたこともありませんでした。その場合、皆さんtarget画面のような画面はStoryboard上でどのように表現されているのでしょうか。

Comment: @troublemaker さん、いろいろやり方はあるだろうと思います。■ 同じStoryboardの中に置いていろんな遷移元の画面からセグエを繋ぐ。(動くと思うんですがやったことはありません。「別の枝に遷移」しているように感じられそうなんで、動くとしてもやりたくはないですね。)■ 同じStoryboardに置くが、どこからもセグエを繋がず、宙ぶらりんにしておく。(私は大抵これです。)■ 他の(大抵は専用の)Storyboard(や時にはxib)に置く。なんてやり方があるでしょう。時間が取れるのであれば、いろいろ試してみると良いと思います。

Comment: @OOPerさん、ありがとうございます！宙ぶらりんにしておくのもアリなんですね！セグエを知ったときから、「ここに置いたものはどこかしらと繋いでおくものだ」と思い込んでいました。専用のStoryboardに置くというのも興味深いです。いろいろ試してみたいと思います。本当にありがとうございました！